# How to assign data to an array?

Tags: matrix

I have a trivial task: I want to create two arrays, assign some numbers to the 1st one, and then assign the same numbers to the second one, but modify the diagonal elements by adding something to them. I do the following (this is just an example, my real problem is much more complicated):

1. I create two arrays `a` and `b` of the 4x4 size and assign some numbers to the array `a`:

```
n = 4;
Array[a, {n, n}];
Array[b, {n, n}];
Do[a[j, k] = If[j == k, j, j + 2*k], {j, n}, {k, n}];
```

2. Then I want to assign the same numbers to the array b and add something else to the diagonal elements. First I assign data of `a` to `b`:

```
b = a;
```

3. At this moment I check, whether the program did everything correctly. It looks fine indeed

```
a[2, 3]
a[1, 4]
b[2, 3]
b[1, 4]
```

```
Out[6]= 8
Out[7]= 9
Out[8]= 8
Out[9]= 9
```

I see that `a` and `b` got correct numbers and `b == a` indeed.

4. Then I try to add something on the diagonal:

```
Do[b[j, j] = a[[j, j]] + j^2, {j, n}];
```

```
Part::partd: Part specification a[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object.
Part::partd: Part specification a[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object.
Part::partd: Part specification a[[2,2]] is longer than depth of object.
General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

but get an error message.

What is wrong here? This is a trivial task for other languages, e.g Fortran. Why such a simple think does not work in Mathematica?

Comment: `a` is an indexed variable, not a list, so you can't use `Part` (`[[...]]`) on it as you do in your second `Do` loop. Use single square brackets instead.

Comment: Thanks for comments! Reply to the 1st comment: I used [..], [[..]] in different combinations, nothing works. What is annoying in the Mathematica "Help" that one can never get really useful information there. For example, I could never find what is the difference between [..] and [[..]] and what is the difference between the words "an indexed variable" and "a list", which were used in the comment.

Comment: @user92593 - See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

n = 4;
```

There is no need to define the array prior to filling it.

```
(aArr = Array[If[#1 == #2, #1, #1 + 2 #2] &, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(bArr = aArr + DiagonalMatrix[Range[n]^2]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note that the [`MatrixForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html) display wrappers are not included in the definitions of the arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not help me. My real problem is much more complicated. Briefly, I need to have a Do loop over a variable N. Inside this loop I need to create a matrix A, read from the disk its diagonal and off-diagonal elements, create the matrix A, then I need to create another loop over a variable c, for each c add a c-dependent vector to the diagonal - this gives the matrix B, calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of B, write results to an external file, then repeat everything for a next c; and all this for a few N. So, I really need Do loops for doing all this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

For example:

```
a = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> i, {i_, j_} :> i + 2 j /; i != j}, {4, 
    4}] // Normal
```

yields: {1, 5, 7, 9}, {4, 2, 8, 10}, {5, 7, 3, 11}, {6, 8, 10, 4}}

```
b = a + DiagonalMatrix[Range[4]^2]
```

yields: {{2, 5, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 8, 10}, {5, 7, 12, 11}, {6, 8, 10, 20}}

or

```
bp = a + SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> i^2, {4, 4}] // Normal
```

yields: {{2, 5, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 8, 10}, {5, 7, 12, 11}, {6, 8, 10, 20}}

or using [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) with `SparseArray`:

```
bb = a + SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> Range[4]^2, {4, 4}]
```

yields: {{2, 5, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 8, 10}, {5, 7, 12, 11}, {6, 8, 10, 20}}

Answer (score 1):

The easiest here (and faster than modifying using Do) is to use Table:

```
n = 4;
a = Table[If[j == k, j, j + 2 k], {j, n}, {k, n}]
```

Comment: Many thanks, SHuisman! Table does work.